# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Fatal exception)

Tags: android, apk

In my apps it is showing me following error when i am deploying my apk file from eclipse to my tab.

```
06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:267)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at Newtons.law.Newton_LawsActivity$1$1.run(Newton_LawsActivity.java:79)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    06-20 18:32:52.550: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

then i am goolge it i get a solution  that ....

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    //unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.rl1));
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    }
```

my whole class code is as follow..
**EDIT**

```
public class Newton_LawsActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnGestureListener,OnDoubleTapListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    OnTouchListener l;
    ImageView animation;
    ImageView hideimage;

    TextView t,s;
    Thread timer;
    int timesleep=0;
    int rid;
    int passid;
    int pausecount=0;
    double pixel,pixel1,pixel2,pixel3;
    String law="null";
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
     AnimationDrawable newtonAnimation;
     int worm_big_count=0;
     int apple_big_count=0;
    float x,y;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        // the frame-by-frame animation defined as a xml file within the drawable folder
            animation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
            //animation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anatomy_5);
            hideimage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagein);
            s=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
            t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            //Starting the first animation.
           passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_00;
           AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
            rid=R.drawable.touchnewtonfinal415;
             law="firstlaw_01";
            animation.setOnTouchListener(this); 
            registerForContextMenu(animation);


        } 
    public void AnimationStart(final int id,final int time){
         timer=new Thread(){
        @Override
            public void run(){
                                try{
                                    Thread.sleep(time);
                                    }catch(Exception e){}
                                    finally{
                                                Newton_LawsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run(){
                                                         animation.setBackgroundResource(id);
                                                         newtonAnimation  = (AnimationDrawable) animation.getBackground();
                                                         newtonAnimation.start();
                                                 }});
                                            }
                                }
                        };
    timer.start();
    }


    private void animationswitch(float x, float y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     pixel = getmaskpixel(x,y,animation,rid);
     pixel1= getmaskpixel(x+2,y,animation,rid);
     pixel2= getmaskpixel(x,y+2,animation,rid);
     pixel3= getmaskpixel(x+2,y+2,animation,rid);
     Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:pixel" + pixel +"pixel1"+pixel1+"pixel2"+pixel2+"pixel3"+pixel3 );
     if ((pixel==-583672 || pixel1==-583672 || pixel2==-583672 || pixel3==-583672 )&& law=="firstlaw_01"){
         passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_01;   //passid is referring animation file 
          law="firstlaw_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
         t.setText("Newton's first law says");
     }else if(((pixel==-1.6711903E7 || pixel1==-1.6711903E7|| pixel2==-1.6711903E7 || pixel3==-1.6711903E7 )||(pixel==-1.6187607E7 || pixel1==-1.6187607E7|| pixel2==-1.6187607E7 || pixel3==-1.6187607E7)) && law=="firstlaw_01"){
         passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_01;
          law="secondlaw_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
          t.setText("Newton's Second law says");
     }else if(((pixel==-1.6761609E7 || pixel1==-1.6761609E7|| pixel2==-1.6761609E7 || pixel3==-1.6761609E7 )||(pixel==-1.6760329E7 || pixel1==-1.6760329E7|| pixel2==-1.6760329E7 || pixel3==-1.6760329E7)||(pixel==-1.6236033E7 || pixel1==-1.6236033E7|| pixel2==-1.6236033E7 || pixel3==-1.6236033E7)||(pixel==-1.6236033E7 || pixel1==-1.6236041E7|| pixel2==-1.6236041E7 || pixel3==-1.6236041E7)) && law=="firstlaw_01"){
         passid=R.drawable.thirdlaw_01;  //passid is referring animation file 
          law="thirdlaw_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
          t.setText("Newton's Third law says");
     }else if((pixel==-1 || pixel1==-1 || pixel2==-1 || pixel3==-1 ) && law=="firstlaw_03"){
         passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_03;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="firstlaw_04";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();

     }else if((pixel==-65536 || pixel1==-65536 || pixel2==-65536 || pixel3==-65536)&& law=="firstlaw_05"){
         passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_05;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="firstlaw_06";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();

     }else if((pixel==-1.2444648E7|| pixel1==-1.2444648E7 || pixel2==-1.2444648E7 || pixel3==-1.2444648E7 ) && law=="firstlaw_07"){
         passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_07;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="firstlaw_08";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();

     }else if((pixel==-1 || pixel1==-1 || pixel2==-1 || pixel3==-1 ) && law=="secondlaw_01"){
         passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_01;

          law="secondlaw_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
          t.setText("Newton's Second law says");

     }else if((pixel==-1 || pixel1==-1 || pixel2==-1 || pixel3==-1 ) && law=="secondlaw_03"){
         passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_03;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="secondlaw_04";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
          t.setText("");

     }else if((pixel==-1 || pixel1==-1 || pixel2==-1 || pixel3==-1 ) && law=="secondlaw_05"){
         passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_05;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="secondlaw_06";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();

     }else if((pixel==-1 || pixel1==-1 || pixel2==-1 || pixel3==-1 ) && law=="secondlaw_07"){
         passid=R.drawable.thirdlaw_01;  //passid is referring animation file 

         law="thirdlaw_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
          t.setText("Newton's Third law says");

     }else if((pixel==-65536 || pixel1==-65536 || pixel2==-65536 || pixel3==-65536 ) && law=="secondlaw_07"){
        if(apple_big_count==0)
            apple_big_count++;
        else 
            apple_big_count--;
         wormappleanimation();
          animationstop_01();

     }else if((pixel==-1.2444648E7 || pixel1==-1.2444648E7 || pixel2==-1.2444648E7 || pixel3==-1.2444648E7 ) && law=="secondlaw_07"){
         if(worm_big_count==0)
                worm_big_count++;
            else 
                worm_big_count--;
             wormappleanimation();
              animationstop_01();

     }else if(((pixel==-1.2444648E7 || pixel1==-1.2444648E7|| pixel2==-1.2444648E7 || pixel3==-1.2444648E7 )||((pixel==-9753559 || pixel1==-9753559|| pixel2==-9753559 || pixel3==-9753559))) && law=="thirdlaw_03"){
         passid=R.drawable.thirdlaw_03;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="thirdlaw_04";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
     }else if((pixel==-65536|| pixel1==-65536 || pixel2==-65536 || pixel3==-65536 ) && law=="thirdlaw_05"){
         passid=R.drawable.thirdlaw_05;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="thirdlaw_06";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
     }else if((pixel==-1|| pixel1==-1 || pixel2==-1 || pixel3==-1 ) && law=="lawmenu"){
          animation.showContextMenu();

     }

     s.setText(Double.toString(pixel));
    }


private void wormappleanimation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(worm_big_count==0 && apple_big_count==0){
        passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_wormapplesmall_01;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="secondlaw07_wormapplesmall_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
    }
    else if(apple_big_count==1 && worm_big_count==0){
        passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_applebig_01;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="secondlaw_07_applebig_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
    }
    else if(apple_big_count==0 && worm_big_count==1){
        passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_wormbig_01;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="secondlaw_07_wormbig_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
    }
    else if(apple_big_count==1 && worm_big_count==1){
        passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_wormapplebig_01;          //passid is referring animation file 
          law="secondlaw_07_wormapplebig_02";                     //changing the law string
          timesleep=0;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 
          animationstop_01();
    }
        s.setText(Float.toString(x)+"-x"+Float.toString(y)+"-y"+Double.toString(pixel)+"-pixcolo");
    }
private double getmaskpixel(float x, float y, ImageView view,int rid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bitmap bm  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), rid);
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) view.getWidth()) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) view.getHeight()) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map

    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // matrix.postRotate(90);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,matrix, false);
    Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image " + bitmap.getWidth() + " OR " +bitmap.getHeight() );
    double bmWidth = view.getWidth();
      double bmHeight = view.getHeight(); 
      if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > bitmap.getWidth() || y > bitmap.getHeight()){
           return 0; //Invalid, return 0 
          }else{
           //Convert touched x, y on View to on Bitmap
           int xBm = (int)(x * (bmWidth /  bitmap.getWidth()));
           int yBm = (int)(y * (bmHeight /  bitmap.getHeight()));
           return bitmap.getPixel((int)xBm,(int) yBm); 
    }

}

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
            float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
            float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        x=e.getX();
        y= e.getY();
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image " + this + " OR " +animation);
        if(pausecount==0){
            pausecount++;
        }else {
            pausecount--;
        }
        pause(pausecount);

        return true;
    }
    public void pause(int pausecount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(pausecount==1){
            hideimage.setVisibility(0);
                try {
                    synchronized (animation) {
                    animation.wait(1000);
                    }
                }catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                pause(pausecount);
           }else{
               hideimage.setVisibility(1);

                animation.notify();

           }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x=e.getX();
        y= e.getY();
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image " + x + " OR " +y);
        animationswitch(x, y);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        Log.w("debug", "MENU pressed");
        animation.showContextMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    void animationstop_01(){
                if(law=="firstlaw_02"){
                        hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.touchnewtonfinal415_282);
                        hideimage.invalidate();
                        rid=R.drawable.touchnewtonfinal415_282;
                        Log.w("debug","it is firstlaw_02");
                        passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_02;          //pass id is referring animation file 
                        law="firstlaw_03";                     //changing the law string
                         timesleep=7750;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                         AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);      //passing the value 

                }else if(law=="firstlaw_04"){
                        hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.touchnewtonfinal415_282);
                        hideimage.invalidate();
                        rid=R.drawable.touchnewtonfinal415_282;
                        Log.w("debug","it is firstlaw_04");
                        passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_04;          //pass id is referring animation file 
                        law="firstlaw_05";                     //changing the law string
                         timesleep=22500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                         AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);                  
                }else if(law=="firstlaw_06"){
                        hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_586);
                        hideimage.invalidate();
                        rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_586;
                        Log.w("debug","it is firstlaw_06");
                        passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_06;          //passid is referring animation file 
                        law="firstlaw_07";                     //changing the law string
                        timesleep=6250;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                        AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);           
                }else if(law=="firstlaw_08"){
                        hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_737);
                        hideimage.invalidate();
                        rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_737;
                        Log.w("debug","it is firstlaw_08");
                        passid=R.drawable.firstlaw_08;          //passid is referring animation file 
                        law="secondlaw_01";                     //changing the law string
                         timesleep=4000;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                         AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="secondlaw_02"){
                         hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_737);
                         hideimage.invalidate();
                         rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_737;
                         Log.w("debug","it is secondlaw_02");
                         passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_02;          //passid is referring animation file 
                         law="secondlaw_03";                     //changing the law string
                         timesleep=7000;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                         AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="secondlaw_04"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_986);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_986;
                          Log.w("debug","it is secondlaw_04");
                          passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_04;          //passid is referring animation file 
                          law="secondlaw_05";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=6500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="secondlaw_06"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1059);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1059;
                          Log.w("debug","it is secondlaw_06");
                          passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_06;          //passid is referring animation file 
                          law="secondlaw_07";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=1500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="secondlaw_07_wormapplebig_02"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1161_01);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1161_01;
                          Log.w("debug","it is secondlaw_07_wormapplebig_02");
                          passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_wormapplebig_02;          //passid is referring animation file 
                          law="secondlaw_07";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=1500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="secondlaw_07_wormbig_02"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1199_01);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1199_01;
                          Log.w("debug","it is secondlaw_07_wormbig_01");
                          passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_wormbig_02;          //pass id is referring animation file 
                          law="secondlaw_07";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=1500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="secondlaw_07_applebig_02"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1128_01);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1128_01;
                          Log.w("debug","it is secondlaw_07_applebig_02");
                          passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_applebig_02;          //pass id is referring animation file 
                          law="secondlaw_07";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=1500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="secondlaw07_wormapplesmall_02"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1093);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1093;
                          Log.w("debug","it is secondlaw07_wormapplesmall_02");
                          passid=R.drawable.secondlaw_07_wormapplesmall_02;          //pass id is referring animation file 
                          law="secondlaw_07";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=1500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="thirdlaw_02"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1322);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1322;
                          Log.w("debug","it is thirdlaw_02");
                          passid=R.drawable.thirdlaw_02;          //passid is referring animation file 
                          law="thirdlaw_03";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=7250;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="thirdlaw_04"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1690);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1690;
                          Log.w("debug","it is thirdlaw_04");
                          passid=R.drawable.thirdlaw_04;          //passid is referring animation file 
                          law="thirdlaw_05";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=16500;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }else if(law=="thirdlaw_06"){
                          hideimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1931);
                          hideimage.invalidate();
                          rid=R.drawable.newtonfinal415_1931;
                          Log.w("debug","it is thirdlaw_06");
                          passid=R.drawable.thirdlaw_06;          //passid is referring animation file 
                          law="lawmenu";                     //changing the law string
                          timesleep=16750;                           //there is no time for sleeping 
                          AnimationStart(passid,timesleep);
                }
```

EDITED

Comment: You are not managing the memory of your application, You loading bitmaps that exceeds your phone's heap memory. please follow this links :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255910/bitmap-memory-leaks/10255989#10255989 and http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Some code samples would be nice, especially from the class Newtons.law.Newton_LawsActivity. 

On a side note: NEVER call System.gc() explicitly!

Comment: @mak_just4anything can you help me understand this thing through code...... i am new to android world

Comment: @Ashishsingh you have to learn yourself, better you understand how to manage memory, you should not load resources when application starts, its not being new to android, its common sense for every programmer to understand the limit of loading resources at right time and freeing them when they have no use. First i advise you to learn java not android and i gave links which are best for any kind of android developer. new, experienced. First clear the fundamentals of OOP and memory management and then start.

Comment: @Ashishsingh generally the error you getting, occurs after sometimes you run the application, but you getting in starting of it, so its worst because the heap memory of a device is 16 MB normally for an application and you loading all resource worth >16 MB at start of application better you think again for it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Activity` called `Newton_LawsActivity` you are setting a background drawable for a `View` which is too large for Android to handle, try looking in your layouts or `Activity` code and remove backgrounds until this error is resolved, then you'll know which background drawable is the culprit, and you could try reducing its size or something.

Comment: caN YOU HELP ME HOW TO OVER COME FROM THIS .... BECAUSE I AM NE W TO ANDROID WORLD

Comment: I've helped you, just look at your Activity code and your layouts in XML, and look for a background pic, and remove it.