# bitmap size exceeds VM budget by calling new Activity

Tags: android

Hi Lets say when i call Activity A to Activity B

**below is my code become**

```
     Intent i = new Intent(TemplateList.this, PictureEditor.class);
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("Key", "2");
     b.putString("Index", imagepathString);
     i.putExtras(b);
     v.getContext().startActivity(i);
     System.gc();
     Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
     finish();
```

Because of in Activity A there are so many objects (so many images) loaded so i am clearing that all objects by **System.gc();
         Runtime.getRuntime().gc();** will be cleared and also destroying activity so no any object will be stay allocated :)

and from **Activity B i am going call to Activity A**

```
        btnTemplate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(PictureEditor.this, TemplateList.class));
            dg.dismiss();
            if (bmp != null) {
                bmp.recycle();
                bmp = null;
            }
            System.gc();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

//Here also i m calling `System.gc` and `Runtime.getRuntime.gc` and destroying activity but do not know why if `activity A` starts than i m getting

**below error**

```
     12-19 12:44:48.769: E/AndroidRuntime(7539): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
     12-19 12:44:48.769: E/AndroidRuntime(7539):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
     12-19 12:44:48.769: E/AndroidRuntime(7539):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:405)
     12-19 12:44:48.769: E/AndroidRuntime(7539):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:418)
     12-19 12:44:48.769: E/AndroidRuntime(7539):    at com.redwood.PictureEditor.get_bitmap(PictureEditor.java:257)
     12-19 12:44:48.769: E/AndroidRuntime(7539):    at com.redwood.PictureEditor$5.run(PictureEditor.java:218)
     12-19 12:44:48.769: E/AndroidRuntime(7539):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Can any body solve my problem :(

Comment: Thanks Pratik Sharma Nice edit :)

Comment: your heap size is increasing annoyingly 
debug the Code and Make Break points where you think it increases the size of the heap

Comment: on either Emulator/Real Device

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitmap recycle with largeHeap enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716574/bitmap-recycle-with-largeheap-enabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling those methods won't work, those methods just say to the GC that "if you want you can run now".

Basically look for those problems:

- Isn't the bitmap too big? -> Rescale it to the minium required size in your app.
- Are you copying the bitmap too much?
- Aren't you leaking the bitmap by leaking the context of your Activity B?

It could come from many places but I would try to downscale it to the minimum required size in your app first.

Comment: but galex ya i am already using options.inSampleSize  and doing in sample size image but my actual question is activity A which is loaded with no of images, and although it is loading properly on first time but in second time it is going to exceeding memory size why? i am already destroying from stack and releasing all the objects then why this is happenig

Answer (score 2):

Its never a good practice to manually call `System.gc();` or `Runtime.getRuntime().gc();`. The better option is to resize/scale your Image according to the screen size using `inSampleSize` or maybe `scaledBitmap()`. You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12819091/726863) which will give you idea that how you can resize/scale the Image before loading it into memory.

Comment: but Lalit ya i am already using options.inSampleSize and doing in sample size image but my actual question is activity A which is loaded with no of images, and although it is loading properly on first time but in second time it is going to exceeding memory size why? i am already destroying from stack and releasing all the objects then why this is happenig

Comment: maybe because something is still there in memory that is causing memory overloaded. Some static data might be there.

Comment: but Lalit i have not used any static data :( You are right because when activity starts again it loaded with more memory i have tested

Comment: probably there is some static data which is not releasing your memory due to which you are getting the exception.

Comment: I have posted whole class can you check this class there is no any static data                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951575/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-by-starting-activity-again

Answer (score 1):

Try to Scale Down The Images You can use this

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

and from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) you can calculate the Size of the image you are getting

Comment: but Usman ya i have use this method and resize image but my actual question is activity A which is loaded with no of images, and although it is loading properly on first time but in second time it is going to exceeding memory size why? i am already destroying from stack and releasing all the objects then why this is happenig

Comment: try to debug your code with break point and get the Heap size how it is increasing