# How to handle large bitmaps in listview in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to display **facebook Newsfeed** in my application. I got the `urls` of the images and I tried to display them by using the  **ImageLoader class** , **MemoryCache class**. I am getting `OOM Exception` because of large Images.

I found in this  [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) that using  **SoftReference or WeakReference will not handle large bitmaps**.
 
To handle this I need to implement Different classes rather than using  past `ImageLoader,MemoryCache,FileCache classes.`

Where can I find those classes?And How to implement them.

```
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class MemoryCache {
    private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
        return ref.get();
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12819091/726863

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitmap recycle with largeHeap enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716574/bitmap-recycle-with-largeheap-enabled)

Answer (score 2):

have a look to this smple project [link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

it is refer as lazy loading of images

Comment: I used the same classes in my application,but the thing is I am getting large Images from facebook api and I want to display them as it is,at this time I am getting OOM Exception because of Large Bitmaps.Is there any way to display Large Bitmaps ?

Comment: after using lazy loading  still exception occurs?

Comment: I am using the above MemoryCache class,did I need to change that?please find the edited post